# How does `npm install npm@latest-2` resolve package version

Tags: node.js, npm

[Here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10214) is an example command for installing npm v2 instead of latest (which is v3):

`npm install -g npm@latest-2`

How does this syntax work?
Usually I use either `latest` or explicit version, but haven't seen such syntax before.

I've tried something similar with other packages, for example:

`npm install express@latest-4`

but it fails with error `No compatible version found: express@latest-4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called tags, and they're intended to allow developers to label particular versions of their packages in a more human readable way.

By default, all versions are tagged as `latest`, but say you have a beta version that you want some users to test - rather than making them specify a particular version to install, you can tag your betas with `npm publish --tag beta`. This will then allow them to run `npm install mypkg@beta` to get the latest beta version.

You can also tag a version after you've already published by using `npm dist-tag add <pkg>@<version> [<tag>]`.

See https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-tags for more info.